# find elements include a text in List

Tags: c#, linq, list, search, find

how i find elements contains a value.

```
 List<int> primes = new List<int>(new int[] { 19, 23,2, 29,23 });

        int index =  primes.IndexOf(2); 
        label1.Text = index.ToString();
        for (int i = index+1; i < primes.Count; )
        {
            index = primes.IndexOf(2, i );
            label1.Text += "-" + index.ToString();
            i = index+1;
        }
```

**Output:**

```
 1-2-3-4
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can You explain your question ? do you want to just find if any element of list contains a specific number ?

Comment: What is it exactly what you need?. Do you need to know if the value exists on the given List? or you need to get that value?

Comment: as you see in my code, indexOf just return elements that their value exactly equal "2". but I want "2" be part of value and have above output.

Comment: @Dima Dima you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
List<int> primes = new List<int>(new int[] { 19, 23, 2, 29, 23 });

label1.Text = String.Join("-", primes.Select((i, inx) => new { i, inx })
                                     .Where(x => x.i.ToString().Contains("2"))
                                     .Select(x => x.inx));
```

Label's text will be `1-2-3-4`

Comment: @Iran_Girl use `!`. `.Where(x => !x.i.ToString().Contains("2"))`

Comment: I'd like learn lambda code to use list. do you know a good ebook to learn it?

Answer (score 0):

to check list for values

```
primes.Contains(2)
```

to know indexes for each element can do

```
var foo = primes.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).ToLookup(x => x.x, x => x.i);
```

this will group elements and their respective indexes

Comment: but contains return true or false. I wanna know the element index. hmm of course I can put in loop. but is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> primes = new List<int>(new int[] { 19, 23,2, 29,23 });

for (int i = 0; i < primes.Count; i++)
{
    if (primes[i].ToString().Contains("2"))
        label1.Text = label1.Text += "-" + i;
}
label1.Text = label1.Text.Substring(1, label1.Text.Length - 1); // this line just removes the dath at the start of the label1.Text
```

this code should do the job but the label1.Text will be 1-2-3-4 cause 2nd 3rt 4th and 5th elements have 2 inside of it or are equal to two